# Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x170e45d00> was mutated while being enumerated - UIImagePickerConteroller didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a native Objective-C application that takes photo using UIImagePickerConteroller. Once UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMedia delegate function return image, I am storing the image in my app document directory and storing the the image location in an array so that I can show it in my application gallery view.

NOT frequently, but once or twice in a month I am receiving a crash log in AppSee/Fabric crash tracker, after user finished taking photo.

[image]

In Appsee video I can see where exactly the crash happened. Crash log says NSArray was mutated while being enumerated(Check the attached image). Now I am NOT doing any addObject or removeObject functionality to my photo mutableArray at the time of enumeration. I am doing a mutable copy of my photo array before reading data to show it my photo gallery. So no chance of mutation while being enumerated.

According to the crash log, it seems like the issue is related to UIImagePickerController. Because the log said -

-[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _postNotification:forEntries:]

-[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _notificationReceiver:]

And 'CAMPriorityNotification' is used by UIImagePickerController class. But not sure if UIImagePickerController is throwing an error and causing crash. I putted @try @catch in didFinishPickingMedia function to find the crash issue. But @try @catch is not throwing an error. So that is making more confusion to me.

Is there anyone faced similar type of crash issue after taking photo? Any suggestion i would appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an apple issue. Apple responded to my bug report. Here is the response from them -

*"Engineering has determined that your bug report (31369562) is a duplicate of another issue (29753773) and will be closed.
The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title, state, product and rank."*

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope. They didn't responded to me yet. Still our old app is crashing in camera view. It's not frequent.

Comment: I eventually stopped using the default camera. Now I'm using ALCameraViewController

Comment: Looks like it is a good camera controller. i will use it in my next project.

Comment: This issue still occurs on iOS 13.6.1

Comment: In iOS 14.0.1 I get this crash much more frequently and always from the same user

Comment: Getting same issue on iOS 14.7.1 

Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x282c02d30> was mutated while being enumerated.
0
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess
2
CoreFoundation
-[__NSSingleObjectEnumerator initWithObject:collection:]
3
CameraUI
-[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _removeObserver:fromObserversByName:]
4
CameraUI
-[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter removeObserver:]
20
libsystem_pthread.dylib
start_wqthread

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your reference to UIImagePickerController* to nil in 2 cases:

1. when you have received image from controller - in function
   "didFinishPickingImage"
2. when you go to background or go back from screen that have link to UIImagePickerController via property. I did it in call viewDidDissapear:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidDissapear:(BOOL)animated {      

     [super viewDidDissapear: animated];   

     self.photoPicker = nil; // that property of type UIImagePickerController*
   ```

   }

   I had a lot of crashes in CAMPriorityNotificationCenter, all in background. After these 2 changes (mentioned above) - crashes didn't appear.

Comment: It's not happening on view closing. It's happening as soon as you comeback from the photo picker controller. It's an apple issue. They fixed it on iOS 12.x

Comment: In my case crash was still repeating in iOS 12.4. Maybe you Saleh Sultan and me have different crashes but in Crashlytics they are looks the same.

Comment: I have the same crashes on iOS 13.1.2 but only on iPad pro devices, 6th and 7th gen iPads are fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting this iOS 14 and 15 regularly until I changed my code to not do anything in the completion handler. I used to do my image saving/processing in there.

This is how it was written:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
  [picker dismissViewControlle Animated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                          // Process and Save Image
                                         }];
}
```

And now I have changed it to:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
  if (picker.isBeingDismissed) {
    return;
  }
  
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                             completion:nil];
  
  // Process and save image
}
```

I was getting this crash a couple of times a week and now its been about 2 weeks without a crash.

*Update* - so I'm still getting these about once a fortnight now. All on 14.* devices...

Answer (score -3):

It looks like your code may access an collection and modify it at the same time.