# iOS 14 App crash frequently when use UIImagePicker to take photos

Tags: crash, ios14, uiimagepicker

on ios 13 this crash occour some time ,but on ios 14 it is reported more frequently. i donot find the same issue that others put，does anyone experienced the same issue， how can I fix this issue？？

it crashed in CameraUI [CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _postNotification:forEntries:]

this is the crash log

```
Last Exception Backtrace (0)#0  (null) in __exceptionPreprocess ()
#1  (null) in objc_exception_throw ()
#2  (null) in __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler ()
#3  (null) in -[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _postNotification:forEntries:] ()
#4  (null) in -[CAMPriorityNotificationCenter _notificationReceiver:] ()
#5  (null) in __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ ()
#6  (null) in ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke ()
#7  (null) in _CFXRegistrationPost ()
#8  (null) in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#9  (null) in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#10 (null) in -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] ()
#11 (null) in __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#12 (null) in _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask ()
#13 (null) in __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke ()
#14 (null) in -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] ()
#15 (null) in -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] ()
#16 (null) in -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] ()
#17 (null) in __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... ()
#18 (null) in +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] ()
#19 (null) in _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext ()
#20 (null) in -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] ()
#21 (null) in __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke ()
#22 (null) in -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] ()
#23 (null) in -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#24 (null) in -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] ()
#25 (null) in -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#26 (null) in __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#27 (null) in -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] ()
#28 (null) in __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke ()
#29 (null) in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#30 (null) in _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 ()
#31 (null) in __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#32 (null) in -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] ()
#33 (null) in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] ()
#34 (null) in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#35 (null) in __CFRunLoopDoSource0 ()
#36 (null) in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#37 (null) in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#38 (null) in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#39 (null) in GSEventRunModal ()
#40 (null) in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#41 (null) in UIApplicationMain ()
#42 0x105789c28 in hook_uiapplication_main ()
#43 0x1051a18dc in main at /Users/cuibaoyin3/Desktop/WorkSpace/DQAppModule/Example/DQAppModule/main.m:15
#44 (null) in start ()
```

Comment: Maybe try this workround below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57962365/5159380.